# getColumnName() return aliasname Oracle

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I am using **ojdbc7.jar** to connect to Oracle from Java. For a query with aliasing, when I do `getColumnName()` and `getColumnLabel()` of `ResultSetMetaData`, both returns the alias name. I want to have the original column name.

Comment: I don't know Java or OJDBC, but even so, I think the answer is obvious: you CAN'T have the original column names, if your functions work on the result set of a query. The result set contains no information about the original column names (or even about whether the data came from one table or two, or whether some columns came from the base tables and others are calculated in the query itself and given a name in the SELECT clause). This is "general principles of computing" rather than strictly Java, Oracle or OJDBC.

Comment: @mathguy That is not entirely true; the `getColumnName()` is **meant** to return the original column name (if available), while `getColumnLabel()` is meant to return the alias (or - if not aliased - the column name). And there are database systems that can return both. It is more likely that Oracle decided to have both return the alias, because historically the JDBC api & specification wasn't really clear on the distinction between the two, so a lot of developers used the wrong one.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Does that mean the tools look at things other than the result set? How can ANY tool in ANY database return the original column name from the result set alone? Do you mean the tools look at the query itself, and not the result of the query?

Comment: Regardless of what the JDBC designers intended or thought possible, @mathguy is right -- the answer to the OP's question is that this cannot be done in Oracle.  Maybe other database implementations allow this, though I cannot imagine how.  What would `getColumnName()` return for `SELECT col1 + col2 + col3 + ... + col50 AS colSum FROM ...`?  And  that's a _simple_ example compared to what could be going on.  Result set columns can be incredibly far removed from table columns.

Comment: @mathguy if you select a column from a table, some database systems will track and communicate both the original name and the alias. That is of course not possible for derived (calculated) fields, or queries with for example unions. As an example, Firebird (whose JDBC driver I maintain) does this, and I believe PostgreSQL does as well.

Comment: @MatthewPeak for derived fields, the column name would generally be an empty string, as specified by JDBC if the information is absent. Although some database system use a fake/generated column name.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible.  If you write a query that aliases the column (or function) as some other name, when the result set is passed to the next level (another query, as in a view, or a JDBC/ODBC call) the metadata that the system has about that query is only the aliased name.

The only way to find the original name is to trace the SQL being used back to its origin (e.g. if it's calling a view, look up the view definition, etc.).

Consider a view that aliases a column to something else (essentially what you are doing since a view is just a stored SQL that's executed on demand).  The view definition of that column will have only the aliased name (it's actually stored that way in dba_tab_columns), not the original name. You have no way of knowing the original name short of looking at the view definition.